# Import sass files into another sass files in Create-react-app not working

Tags: reactjs, sass, create-react-app

It's as simple as this, I have `App.scss` and `hello.scss`in the same dir.

When I import : `@import 'hello.scss'` in App.scss

I got this error 
[image]

All what `hello.scss` contain is `.hello color: red;`

mention that I have `node-sass` and `sass-loader` installed.

Comment: `.hello color: red` should be `.hello { color: red }`

Comment: @MorKadosh dude I been stuck on this for 4 hours and then realize is stupid syntax error, Thank you!